# How to share JavaScript across Salesforce Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have many `helper` methods which I copy from one Salesforce Lightning component `helper` JavaScript file to another.

**Example common helper method**

```
callAction : function(cmp, methodName, params, callback){
    var action = cmp.get(methodName); 
    action.setParams(params);   
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if(cmp.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS"){
            var result = response.getReturnValue();
            if (callback) callback(result);
        } else if (state === "ERROR"){
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log(errors[0].message);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    $A.getCallback(function() {
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    })();  
},
```

These generic style methods are useful in most components.

I would like a central location for all my common JavaScript methods which is accessible from all my custom Salesforce Lightning components.

And I would like this central location to be easily editable.

How could I achieve this with Salesforce Lightning?

Answer (score 2):

Better approach is to have all reusable code inside static resource. Refer [Sharing JavaScript Code Across Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_share_code.htm).

We had performance issues with storing reusable JavaScript inside extendible components. Each component separately loads Its instance of extended class, with static resource they can be loaded just once when having a complex embedded components in a application.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a fan of the inheritance for lightning components as currently implemented by Salesforce. So, I've made my own [Service Component Design Pattern](https://github.com/tsalb/sfdc-lightning-service-components).

This is a pattern based off some previous blogs, but yes, I prefer to call methods (just a style thing) explicitly after dropping them into a component. This way I can create a bunch of micro-services and "compose" a bigger component from it.

FYI, you can take advantage of the fact all instances of the same component share one instance of a helper class.